# New List with values filtered from previous list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used a formula which is most likely not the most appropriate to generate a list of serial numbers.
The serial number represents each day (i.e. 001 is the 1st, 027 is the 27th.) I have two values for every day of the month. This is because a second task is performed every Monday. For example, the serial numbers for the 6th March are both 006 and 106, and for the 13th March they are 013 and 113. However the method I chose to create the list of serial numbers was `=IF(COUNTIF((CHOOSE(F33,fjan,ffeb,fmar,fapr,fmay,fjun,fjul,faug,fsep,foct,fnoc,fdec)),D45)>0,C45,A33)`

I did this for every serial number beginning 0, and as such each s/n that does not fall on a Monday results in the s/n 100. There is no 0th of a month so this is perfect for me. I just need to figure out now how to create a list from my existing list that excludes the 100s, so that I can have one list without gaps that I can reference on the jobcards. Please see this screenshot for visual.

[image: definition of S/N]
[image: named range:cereal]
[image: what I want]

I have no idea how to create a list that does not just have if this else that results as seen above with the 001,No,002,No list in H column.

I can't use plugins as it has to go back on to a sharepoint with only base excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 this would work:

```
=LET(start, DATE(G2,F3,1),
     end,   EOMONTH(start,0)+1,
     sq,    SEQUENCE(end-start,,start),
DROP(
     REDUCE(  0,  sq,
     LAMBDA(  a,  b,
     VSTACK(  a,
              IF(
                 WEEKDAY(b)=2,
                 {0;1},
                 0)
              &  TEXT(DAY(b),"00")))),1))
```

[image]

Or if you need `No` in between:

```
=LET(start, DATE(G2,F3,1),
     end,   EOMONTH(start,0)+1,
     sq,    SEQUENCE(end-start,,start),
DROP(
     REDUCE(  0,  sq,
     LAMBDA(  a,  b,
     VSTACK(  a,
              "No",
              IF(
                 WEEKDAY(b)=2,
                 {0;1},
                 0)
              &  TEXT(DAY(b),"00")))),1))
```

[image]

It uses the values in `F3` (month number) and `G2` (year) for the start date of the month and creating a sequence of all days from that month (sequence of first day of next month - start date starting from the first day of the month).

Then if the day is a Monday add a `0` in front of the day number formatted as text in two digits (`"00"`) as well as a leading `1`. If no Monday only have a leading `0`.

Comment: Accepted answer pending edit for one line of code. WEEKDAY(b)=2, gives Sunday, corrected to =3 to give Monday. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Actually with me WEEKDAY(b)=2 gives Monday for me (see what happens if I change the day number to the text equivalent: ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMUr6.jpg maybe that's environment related (different language settings?, European, Dutch environment)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a this says 2 should represent Monday as well

Comment: is it not because you have set the day to 0, rather than 1 in the code snippet you posted? 

"2 Numbers 1 (Monday) through 7 (Sunday).

3 Numbers 0 (Monday) through 6 (Sunday)."

Comment: May be regional, I am GB. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a

Comment: If omitted it behaves like 

Numbers 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday),  so 2 is Monday.